# How can I increment a list within a loop without a second loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

I am trying to loop through an array of month end dates t within my current loop without creating another for loop.

```
t=np.array([[30],[31],[31],[31],[28],[31],[31]])
n = 7
for i in range(0, n):
    print(i * t)
```

expected output :

`0,31,62,93...`

Comment: hmmm, maybe question is what is expected ouput? How avoid loops?

Comment: I don't see how that output would be correct. You seem to sum up everything except the first one. Why is the output not 30, 61, 92, ...?

Comment: @ThomasWeller my output was wrong, I edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here loop is not necessary use:

```
a = t * np.arange(n)[:, None]
print (a)
[[  0]
 [ 31]
 [ 62]
 [ 93]
 [112]
 [155]
 [186]]
```

Or:

```
a = t[:, 0] * np.arange(n)
print (a)
[  0  31  62  93 112 155 186]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use i as an index for t.

```
t=np.array([[30],[31],[31],[31],[28],[31],[31]])
n = 7
for i in range(0, len(t)):
    print (i * t[i])
```